# What did Joe mean by saying "Ain't that the sad truth" in this particular scene?

Tags: plot-explanation, reservoir-dogs

In the Reservoir Dogs (1992) movie, during a phone call between Boss Joe and Sid, gangster Blonde walks
into Joe’s room:

> Joe: Ηow does freedom feel, huh?
>
> Blonde: It’s a change.
>
> Joe: **Ain’t that the sad truth**.

What Joe meant by saying "Ain't that the sad truth" in this particular scene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What Joe meant by saying "Ain't that the sad truth"?

[Forget about it](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119008/characters/nm0000136) said [Captain Obvious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Obvious).

To me, that's exactly that: a *[lapalissade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lapalissade)*, expressed with different words. You have many ways, many expressions to achieve that. Life is very different from inside/outside prison... duh!

But you can also take that expression with irony, and understand it as: no difference between life in prison and outside, because these folks will live the same way no matter what.